# DotNetOpenAuth not working for oauth2

Tags: authorization, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I downloaded the latest package through Nuget, and installed using the package manager.

Issues:
1) First, I did not see DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2 in the references. I had to google around like a wild child to get this through another nuget install
2) After doing that, the IAuthorizationServerHost interface is not being recognized.

I am just getting started using DotNetOpenAuth2, but the lack of proper steps and documentation is frankly a turn off. Not everyone using this has built an authorization server before. Any help in getting me up and running is greatly appreciated

Comment: Ranting and asking for general help is not really a question. I encourage you to use the dotnetopenid@googlegroups.com mailing list.

Comment: I have been pretty specific in what my issues were. I cannot be more specific when all I was trying to do was get myself started. Anyway, thanks for pointing me to the group

Comment: Yes you have been specific about issues. But this isn't an issues list. This is a q&a forum. And I see no question here. I see a request for 'any help', but it isn't even clear what you need, since it sounds like you have already overcome at least some of the issues.

Comment: Yeah, I was unsure myself as to what exactly I needed. I apologize for that. The problem I was having was specifically that IAuthorizationServerHost interface was not being recognized, but it's solved now, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to use NuGet, you can try out DotNetOpenAuth.Ultimate  http://nuget.org/packages/DotNetOpenAuth.Ultimate

`A single assembly that adds OpenID 1.1/2.0, OAuth 1.0(a)/2.0, & InfoCard authentication and authorization functionality for client and server applications.`

```
PM> Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.Ultimate
```

Comment: Ah, this would have helped. Thanks! Wonder why their site doesn't link to this

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that downloading it manually, and then adding the dll manually fixes my issues.